# Validate exist mobile number as per starting series

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have mobile number more than 50K, and I need to validate all number, whether these are valid number or not as per Indian mobile number series. I have downloaded Indian mobile number series from Wikipedia, and storing these in column named Series in another table. Now I want to validate all number in one go, please provide any standard query which is faster, and in best plan execution.

For example series is: 6000,6001,6002,9977,9947
Below is mobile number: 1241124154,6011101101,8414141401,6014141410,9947256585

Please note that above number is randomly entered, these are not related to the number I have in my record. Any resemblance/existence  of this number will be just coincidence.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Show us some more numbers to validate, and also which ones of them who are valid. (The example series is just fine.)

Comment: SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can determine valid phone matches using known *prefixes* of the numbers, you should be able to just index the phone number column and then run something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    phone LIKE '6000%' OR
    phone LIKE '6002%' OR
    phone LIKE '9977%' OR
    phone LIKE '9947%';
```

If you have many possible phone prefixes to check, then I suggest the following approach.  First, create a new column based on the phone number which contains only the prefix.  You may do this in your current table, or you may create a temporary table if you don't want to/can't change your current schema.  Next, create a new table which contains just a single column.  Populate this table with your 4000 actual valid phone prefixes, and then index this phone column.  Now, the following query should be very fast:

```
SELECT t1.phone
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM prefixes t2 WHERE t2.prefix = t1.prefix);
```

Your SQL database should be able to use the index to satisfy the `WHERE` clause, and make the query execute quickly.

Comment: Thanks, but there are just 4 mobile number series given for example, total number of series is about 4K, that mean I will need to write llike 4K times. That will impact sql performance. Can it be done using cursor or anything best deal so that repetition of like can be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

use some thing like this, If you have mobile master table name tblmobile and series in tblmobileseries table then below is a sample query for your solution

```
SELECT mobileno,
(case when exists(select tm.mobileno 
                  from tblmobile tm, tblmobileseries tms 
                  where tm.mobileno Like tms.series + '%')
      then 'VALID' 
      else 'Not Valid' end
) as ISValid 
from tblmobileno
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DM](
 [Zone] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [State_Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [LCO_Code] [float] NULL,
 [LCO_Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Status] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [lco_type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [LCO_Creation_Date] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Contact_MobileNo] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [email] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: USE [DM_ContactCheck]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SeriesT]    Script Date: 11/15/2019 3:29:28 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SeriesT](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Series] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: Error:        Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.

Comment: inplace of tms.series in the above query use CAST(tms.series as varchar(10)) it would work then

Comment: in below query it is giving all record with valid remarks, wheres it shall display 4 not valid records as per my database

Comment: SELECT Contact_MobileNo,
(case when exists(select tm.Contact_MobileNo 
                  from #NewTempTable tm, SeriesT tms 
                  where tms.Series=LEFT(tm.Contact_MobileNo,4))
      then 'VALID' 
      else 'Not Valid' end
) as ISValid 
from #NewTempTable

Comment: SELECT t1.Contact_MobileNo
FROM #NewTempTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SeriesT t2 WHERE t2.Series = LEFT(t1.Contact_MobileNo,4))

Comment: Pramod the query shared by you, always give valid and not valid data with 'Valid' remarks.I am just learner now, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Select M.Mobile,
Case When Exists (Select 1 from SeriesT T where Left(M.Mobile,4)=T.Series)
Then 'Valid'
Else 'Invalid'
End as Result
From DM M

DM- Table for mobile number
SeriesT- Table for mobile number series